# How to make "*.sh" executable on Hyper-V shared drivers

Tags: bash, 22.04, hyper-v

When enabling the **Enhanced Session Mode** in **Hyper-V** and shared a "`D:\`" drivers to the **Ubuntu guest VM**,
all "`*.sh`" files inside the shared "`D:\`" drivers will only have "`rw`" permissions and the "`x`" permission is missing when checking by "`ls -alith`"

It seems that Hyper-V `mounts` the shared "`D:\`" drivers as "`read-write`" only but not `executable`.

How to make Hyper-V to mount all **shared drivers** as `executable` for all "`*.sh`" files?
Or
How to mount the shared Hyper-v drivers manually inside the guest Ubuntu vm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 mount -o remount,exec  /path/to/mountpoint
```

Apart from that, the .sh file has to have the exec bit set. You can view that using ls -l ..., and if necessary set with something like:

```
chmod ug+x /path/to/*.sh
```